# How to decode back the encoded base64 .jpeg image in AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, image, ionic-framework

I have some problem in my ionic app, I want to update the image before sending it to server, so I have captured image and encoded in base64 jpeg format. I want that format to be decoded into something like "name.jpg" and it should exactly have same name what php file decode and here is my encoded code in AngularJS and decoded code in php

Angular code:

```
$scope.takePicture = function(source)
{
    var options = { 
        quality : 85, 
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
        sourceType : source,
        allowEdit : true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 180,
        targetHeight: 180,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

        $scope.imgURI= "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;


    }, function(err) {
        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });

}
```

php code:

```
if (array_key_exists('picture', $data))
{
    define('UPLOAD_DIR','../images/user_img/'); // Change your path location here and change permission to 777 ***
    $img = $picture;
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $dataimg = base64_decode($img);
    $filename = uniqid().'.jpeg';
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR.$filename;
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $dataimg);
    $picture = $filename;
    //log_message('info', $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.');
}
```